# Adding subitem in listview using parse.com through parse query

Tags: android, eclipse, parse-platform, subitem, android-parsequeryadapter

i have displayed the data in listview from parse, the data that should be displayed is the username as item and bloodgroup of that user as the subitem. my app is displaying the item but i just don't know how to display the subitem. feild names from parse is "username" and "BloodGroup". please how can i display subitem.

here is the code for that

```
public class donar_list extends Activity {
// Declare Variables
 ListView listview;
 SimpleCursorAdapter adapter;
 List<ParseObject> ob;

   ProgressDialog mProgressDialog;
     // ParseQueryAdapter<ParseObject> adapter;


   @Override
   public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.donar_acceptor_list);

    ParseQueryAdapter.QueryFactory<ParseObject> factory =
             new ParseQueryAdapter.QueryFactory<ParseObject>() {
               public ParseQuery create() {
                 ParseQuery query = new ParseQuery("Data");
                 query.orderByDescending("createdAt");
                 query.whereContains("DonAcc", "donar");
                 return query;
               }
             };

         ParseQueryAdapter<ParseObject> Adapter = newParseQueryAdapter<ParseObject>    (this, factory);
         Adapter.setTextKey("username");
         final ListView listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list);
         listView.setAdapter(Adapter);
      }
    }
```

For layout

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
 android:layout_width="fill_parent"
 android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

 <ListView
    android:id="@+id/list"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    />


 </RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: you need to have a custom adapter to display multiple items in single list item...

Comment: I do edited my layout. but i'm just not getting the idea that how can i display data on subitem from the class?

Comment: What i mean to say is you can't use `SimpleCursorAdapter` for you purpose, you need to have an `ArrayAdpter` and `CustomLayout` for this purpose.

Comment: Can you provide me some code for this? edit my code as you wish !

Comment: You can look here for good tutorial http://www.mkyong.com/android/android-listview-example/ `Custom ArrayAdapter example`

Comment: what will bw the difference if i do this by simply hard coding the values of the list or retrieve tha data from parse table?

Comment: Because it is hard coded here and in most of the tutorials